# CMS made simple - adding a php form

Tags: php, content-management-system, cmsmadesimple

I'm trying to add a PHP form to a website I'm working on. Not real familiar with PHP, but I've put the file in the `upload` folder in the CMS.

I think I've linked the jQuery and other files correctly and I've edited the PHP file putting in emails etc. This one also calls on another PHP validation file.

Anyway it shows up normally and I can fill it out but it goes to a `404` page and doesn't work.

My question is, what linking convention do I use to link to the php file and is it in the right place? I use cPanel where the CMS is installed.

Instead of putting: `action="url([[root_url]]/uploads/scripts/form-to-email.php"`
should I just put: `action="uploads/scripts/form-to-email.php"`?

The page in question is here: [www.edelweiss-web-design.com.au/captainkilowatt/](http://www.edelweiss-web-design.com.au/captainkilowatt/)

Also, anyone know a good captcha I can integrate with it...? Thanks!

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
    <form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="uploads/scripts/form-to-email.php">

        <div class="control-group">
            <label>Your Name</label>
            <input class="fullname" type="text" name="fullname" />
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input class="email" type="text" name="email" />
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label>Phone (optional)</label>
            <input class="phone" type="text" name="phone" />
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <label>Message</label>
            <textarea class="message" name="message"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div id="errors"></div>

        <div class="control-group no-margin">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
        </div>

    </form>
    <div id='msg_submitting'><h2>Submitting ...</h2></div>
    <div id='msg_submitted'><h2>Thank you !<br> The form was submitted Successfully.</h2></div>
</div>
```

Here is the php:

```
<?php
/*
Configuration
You are to edit these configuration values. Not all of them need to be edited.
However, the first few obviously need to be edited.
EMAIL_RECIPIENTS - your email address where you want to get the form submission.

*/

$email_recipients = "contact@edelweiss-web-design.com.au";//<<=== enter your email address here
//$email_recipients = "mymanager@gmail.com,his.manager@yahoo.com"; <<=== more than one recipients like this


$visitors_email_field = 'email';//The name of the field where your user enters their email address
//This is handy when you want to reply to your users via email
//The script will set the reply-to header of the email to this email
//Leave blank if there is no email field in your form
$email_subject = "New Form submission";

$enable_auto_response = true;//Make this false if you donot want auto-response.

//Update the following auto-response to the user
$auto_response_subj = "Thanks for contacting us";
$auto_response ="
Hi

Thanks for contacting us. We will get back to you soon!

Regards
Captain Kilowatt
";

/*optional settings. better leave it as is for the first time*/
$email_from = ''; /*From address for the emails*/
$thank_you_url = 'http://www.edelweiss-web-design.com.au/captainkilowatt.html';/*URL to redirect to, after successful form submission*/

/*
This is the PHP back-end script that processes the form submission.
It first validates the input and then emails the form submission.
The variable $_POST contains the form submission data.
*/
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// note that our submit button's name is 'submit'
// We are checking whether submit button is pressed
// This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!".print_r($_POST,true);
exit;
}

require_once "http://edelweiss-web-design.com.au/captainkilowatt/upload/scripts/formvalidator.php";
//Setup Validations
$validator = new FormValidator();
$validator->addValidation("fullname","req","Please fill in Name");
$validator->addValidation("email","req","Please fill in Email");
//Now, validate the form
if(false == $validator->ValidateForm())
{
echo "<B>Validation Errors:</B>";

$error_hash = $validator->GetErrors();
foreach($error_hash as $inpname => $inp_err)
{
echo "<p>$inpname : $inp_err</p>\n";
}
exit;
}
$visitor_email='';
if(!empty($visitors_email_field))
{
$visitor_email = $_POST[$visitors_email_field];
}

if(empty($email_from))
{
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$email_from ="forms@$host";
}

$fieldtable = '';
foreach ($_POST as $field => $value)
{
if($field == 'submit')
{
continue;
}
if(is_array($value))
{
$value = implode(", ", $value);
}
$fieldtable .= "$field: $value\n";
}

$extra_info = "User's IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";

$email_body = "You have received a new form submission. Details below:\n$fieldtable\n $extra_info";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
@mail(/*to*/$email_recipients, $email_subject, $email_body,$headers);

//Now send an auto-response to the user who submitted the form
if($enable_auto_response == true && !empty($visitor_email))
{
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
@mail(/*to*/$visitor_email, $auto_response_subj, $auto_response,$headers);
}

//done.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest')
{
//This is an ajax form. So we return success as a signal of succesful processing
echo "success";
}
else
{
//This is not an ajax form. we redirect the user to a Thank you page
header('Location: '.$thank_you_url);
}
?><?php
/*
Configuration
You are to edit these configuration values. Not all of them need to be edited.
However, the first few obviously need to be edited.
EMAIL_RECIPIENTS - your email address where you want to get the form submission.

*/

$email_recipients = "contact@edelweiss-web-design.com.au";//<<=== enter your email address here
//$email_recipients = "mymanager@gmail.com,his.manager@yahoo.com"; <<=== more than one recipients like this


$visitors_email_field = 'email';//The name of the field where your user enters their email address
//This is handy when you want to reply to your users via email
//The script will set the reply-to header of the email to this email
//Leave blank if there is no email field in your form
$email_subject = "New Form submission";

$enable_auto_response = true;//Make this false if you donot want auto-response.

//Update the following auto-response to the user
$auto_response_subj = "Thanks for contacting us";
$auto_response ="
Hi

Thanks for contacting us. We will get back to you soon!

Regards
Captain Kilowatt
";

/*optional settings. better leave it as is for the first time*/
$email_from = ''; /*From address for the emails*/
$thank_you_url = 'http://www.edelweiss-web-design.com.au/captainkilowatt.html';/*URL to redirect to, after successful form submission*/

/*
This is the PHP back-end script that processes the form submission.
It first validates the input and then emails the form submission.
The variable $_POST contains the form submission data.
*/
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
// note that our submit button's name is 'submit'
// We are checking whether submit button is pressed
// This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
echo "error; you need to submit the form!".print_r($_POST,true);
exit;
}

require_once "http://www.edelweiss-web-design.com.au/captainkilowatt/upload/scripts/formvalidator.php";
//Setup Validations
$validator = new FormValidator();
$validator->addValidation("fullname","req","Please fill in Name");
$validator->addValidation("email","req","Please fill in Email");
//Now, validate the form
if(false == $validator->ValidateForm())
{
echo "<B>Validation Errors:</B>";

$error_hash = $validator->GetErrors();
foreach($error_hash as $inpname => $inp_err)
{
echo "<p>$inpname : $inp_err</p>\n";
}
exit;
}
$visitor_email='';
if(!empty($visitors_email_field))
{
$visitor_email = $_POST[$visitors_email_field];
}

if(empty($email_from))
{
$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$email_from ="forms@$host";
}

$fieldtable = '';
foreach ($_POST as $field => $value)
{
if($field == 'submit')
{
continue;
}
if(is_array($value))
{
$value = implode(", ", $value);
}
$fieldtable .= "$field: $value\n";
}

$extra_info = "User's IP Address: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";

$email_body = "You have received a new form submission. Details below:\n$fieldtable\n $extra_info";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
@mail(/*to*/$email_recipients, $email_subject, $email_body,$headers);

//Now send an auto-response to the user who submitted the form
if($enable_auto_response == true && !empty($visitor_email))
{
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
@mail(/*to*/$visitor_email, $auto_response_subj, $auto_response,$headers);
}

//done.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest')
{
//This is an ajax form. So we return success as a signal of succesful processing
echo "success";
}
else
{
//This is not an ajax form. we redirect the user to a Thank you page
header('Location: '.$thank_you_url);
}
?>
```

I've added the php file. 
So, in the action part, when I submit the form, it no longer gives me a 404 but takes me to a blank page with the 'form-to-email.php' page. However, the script is not working from what I can tell. Again, I know html and css, and  little javascipt, but how php is meant to work...?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please make sure that your question is complete as described here in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You will get quicker and better responses on complete questions.

Comment: You should put your contact form html in your question, but your problem is that you have a series of urls that are (likely) based on some sort of replacement scheme or template library, so you have a bunch of bad urls like `url([[root_url]]/uploads/scripts/form-to-email.php` where `[[root_url]]` is not parsing as you intend.

Comment: Hi Rasclatt, I just edited my question about what you have mentioned. [ [root_url] ] works from the CSS style sheet just fine in CMSMS, but maybe not from the template...

Comment: Yeah I don't think it works on the actual html. If you view your browser source, you will see you have 5-6 broken links, all the links that contain that `[[root_url]]`

Comment: Also, you should just remove the `[[root_url]]` or make a php function that will replace that particular string with the host name.

Comment: I'll try it tonight (AEST), can't access the pages right now - incidentally, in the 'form-to-email.php' file, it links to a 'validation.php' file which is in the same folder(same level). Do I write in the full URL to this second file, or is there a shorter way like '.../validation.php' ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using one of the modules for CMS instead of trying to build form in PHP from scratch. It is much more safer to use CMS buildin functions and that is the point of using the CMS in the first place. For CMS made simple the formbuilder module is here:
http://dev.cmsmadesimple.org/projects/formbuilder

Comment: I can't get form builder to work. the cms_mailer module is depreciated and the form builder relies on this. I've tried manually uploading the latest versions, uninstalling, re-installing to no avail.

Comment: Ok, the form is sending emails - yipeee! However, the validation is not working. Got the following error message: Warning: require_once(formvalidator.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/edelw250/public_html/captainkilowatt/uploads/scripts/form-to-email.php on line 51

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'formvalidator.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/edelw250/public_html/captainkilowatt/uploads/scripts/form-to-email.php on line 51          I assume I have to change a path in the php file...?

Comment: In most cases you should not have to. Find where the file formvalidator.php is and you should make correct include_path (might be missing /home/edelw250/public_html/captainkilowatt/). Alternatively first try to change the one require_once to test if the validation works (assuming formvalidator.php does not require more classes).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments.

I found another form with a captcha (PHP) and preserved the whole structure by uploading it as is into CMSMS uploads folder. 
I then used iframe to embed the form on my page, changed a couple of little details with the CSS and wording, and bob's your uncle, it works just fine.

For anyone interested, I used: www.html-form-guide.com/contact-form/creating-a-contact-form.html

This is free and I am certainly not trying to spam as I am in no way affiliated with this site or any sites associated with it.